# How to make my paragraph not to scroll down but to stay in place? Nesting scrolls

Tags: html, css

What I try to achieve here is to have main layout with fixed header that would scroll its `main` content when needed (main content changes) but yet having some sort of control on how `main` content scroll itself

I would like for my header as well as paragraph to stay on top and only list with scrollable items should be scrollable. How can I achieve that without removing `div.mywrap` element? `Header` stays where it should as I would like to, but I cannot do the same thing insinde `main` tag that paragraph would stay on top and rest of the content would scroll

Here is my complete code and example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwgd26vt/23/

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

header{
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
p{
  background-color: blue;
}

.mywrap{
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 400px;
}

main{
    display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scrollable{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="mywrap">
<header>
  IM a HEADER and I ALWAYS want to be ON TOP
</header>
<main>
  <section class="aot">
    <p>
       I want this paragraph to NOT TO SCROLL DOWN and be on top as well
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class='scrollable'>
  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>
    <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>
    <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
   scrollable item
  </div>  <div>
  scrollable item </div>
  </section>
</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Clearly that first paragraph should be *inside* the fixed header... No?

Comment: I think the linked demo (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wem90obx/) answers your question, but I feel like I must be missing something, given that you haven't really provided an adequate amount of code. You mention in your question that the: "*`main` layout with fixed header that would scroll its `main` content when needed (`main` content changes)*" but provide no means by which the content changes, or demonstrate "*how [the] main content [scrolls] itself*." (Having left this comment, as is so often the case, I think Paulie_D may have the better solution.)

Comment: As of broad context, its Angular SPA, where `main` contains `router-outlet`. Therfore main contains content of route components in which I would like NOT to have to remember to handle scrolling (therfore, "autoscroll") but in one specific case of component, its "title" should not be scrollable - which is a wannabe-on-top paragraph here.

Answer (score 0):

I created this example i hope useful this:

Header and paragraph stay fixed at the top, and only the scrollable section scrolls. The `overflow: hidden` on the `main` element hides the overflow initially, and `overflow: auto` on the scrollable section enables scrolling when needed. The `flex-grow: 1` on the scrollable section allows it to take up the remaining space

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .mywrap {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    header {
      background-color: red;
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .aot p {
      background-color: blue;
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .scrollable {
      overflow: auto;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .scrollable p {
      padding: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mywrap">
    <header>
      IM a HEADER and I ALWAYS want to be ON TOP
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="aot">
        <p>
          I want this paragraph to NOT TO SCROLL DOWN and be on top as well
        </p>
      </section>
      <section class="scrollable">

        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
        <p>scrollable item</p>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
```